# Bing Map Longitude Latitude Data Binding

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, bing-maps

Is it unable to bind the longitude and latitude ?

```
<bm:Map x:Name="EventMap" MapType="Birdseye" ZoomLevel="5" 
        Credentials="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" Height="480" Width="550" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <bm:Map.Center>
        <bm:Location Latitude="{Binding Latitude}"
                     Longitude="{Binding Longitude}"/>
    </bm:Map.Center>
</bm:Map>
```

Here is the Collection which bind with the Latitude and Longitude.

```
<CollectionViewSource
    x:Name="itemsViewSource"
    Source="{Binding EventItems}"
    d:Source="{Binding EventItemGroups[0].EventItems, Source={d:DesignInstance Type=data:EventDataSource, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}"/>
```

What kind of data types i should use? String? Double or others?

```
 private string _longitude = string.Empty;
        public string Longitude
        {
            get { return this._longitude; }
            set { this.SetProperty(ref this._longitude, value); }
        }

        private string _latitude = string.Empty;
        public string Latitude
        {
            get { return this._latitude; }
            set { this.SetProperty(ref this._latitude, value); }
        }
```

I believe (longitude) "151.173248", (latitude) "-33.840764" is a valid point which is Sydney if i m not wrong.

Because i found that the map is not showing the Latitude and Longitude i bind. It seem to be the original map without any location. Most important, after few time of compile, it pop out

> failed to assign to property 'Bing.Maps.Location.Longitude

Any idea wat happen?

Comment: Where are the Latitude and Longitude values you are trying to bind from, did you remember to assign the proper DataContext for your UI element that contains the map?  If the DataContext is set up properly, are you sure your Latitude and Longitude values are valid?

Comment: @BojinLi
Thanks for replying. Here is the info.

Answer (score 0):

Part of your pasted code is kind of confusing, I could be dense but I don't know what you are using the `CollectionViewSource` for.  Your Longitude and Latitude Properties seem suspicious though.  According to the [Reference Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846500.aspx), `<bm:Map.Center>` takes a `Location` object, which in turn expect Longitude and Latitude as doubles.  I am quite certain that binding a source string property to a target double property will not work by default.  You will have to specify a value converter.  In your case, just use double for your Longitude and Latitude Properties if possible:

```
    private double _longitude = Double.NaN;
    public double Longitude
    {
        get { return _longitude; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _longitude, value); }
    }

    private double _latitude = Double.NaN;
    public double Latitude
    {
        get { return _latitude; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _latitude, value); }
    }
```

I also noticed that your Longitude and Latitude Properties are not Dependency Properties, and you don't seem to be implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, unless you are doing it inside SetProperty()  Just keep in mind that as a result, your `<bm:Map.Center>` will not update if you subsequently change the Longitude or Latitude property in code, even though you might think it would because of databinding.

Comment: Thanks for replying. 
Sorry for the messy code. Actually i am modifying from the original example. Besides, i tried the solution u gave. It seem still the same ><. I guess i din subsequently change my longitude and latitude. The map is on another page. I just wish to display the location once i load into the page. So should not be a problem. ><